# Prooving the convergence rate of noisy estimators (machine Learning)

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, estimators, noise

I want to estimate a quantity and have two choices for estimators (they both sample from the same distribution). I suspect one of them is nosier and has a slower convergence rate. I want to mathematically proove this, but I don't know where to start. Is there standard reference in statistics that I can consult for example proofs of convergence rates in ML/statistics?

Comment: Is this purely theoretical or do you have some data?

Comment: I am working with data. The estimator is computed over a discrete distribution of actions the model can choose from.